# How to style row header column in DataGrid

Tags: xaml, datagrid, styling, rowdetails

I am using ComponentOne C1DataGrid. I have been able to style it to the full extent except row header column.

How can I style it in XAML?

You can see the image:
[here](http://i44.tinypic.com/nwabdl.png)
Thanks,
flot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case somebody else is interesting:

There is a special presenter, DataGridRowHeaderPresenter, that can be styled.
I wanted to replace a standard row details toggle with the tree-like "+" and "-" signs and I did it as follows:

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridRowHeaderStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type c1:DataGridRowHeaderPresenter}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c1:DataGridRowHeaderPresenter}">
                <!-- BulletDecorator is used to provide baseline alignment between the sign and the Content -->
                <BulletDecorator Background="#BFEFF2F5">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Grid Width="13" Height="13">
                            <Image Name="sign" Source="/myControls;component/Resources/Images/plus.png" />
                        </Grid>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Source"  Value="/myControls;component/Resources/Images/minus.png"  TargetName="sign"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```